# Inputmask IE11 issue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I am writing vue.js code and using v-inputmask, actually v-inputmask works really well at Google Chrome but ı get that result when ı try to run my app at Internet Explorer 11

[image]

I set the input disable in the first input field, and set the disable in the second, when I get the value disable, I get this error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hello,  in order to get good answers on this site you need to be really specific in your questions and it is extremely helpful if you provide code examples to help illustrate your problem.

Comment: When you get the value, what error are you meeting? Try to use F12 developer tools to debug your code, and check the detailed error message. Besides, can you post enough code or create a simple sample about the input mask textbox, it will be easier for us to help you reproduce the problem and solve it.